# How to select drop down option in Selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I am trying to select drop down in Selenium webdriver.

Here is my code:

```
package Select;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.jetty.html.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class NewTest {


    public WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup(){
        //Open URL in Browser
        driver.get("http://www.homeshop18.com/"); 
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
        // Maximize the window.
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }


    @Test 
    public void EnterData(){
        Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='q_category']")));
        select.deselectAll();
        select.selectByVisibleText("15095");

    }

}
```

But I am getting this Error:

```
The constructor Select(WebElement) is undefined
```

Comment: can you tell me the `import` statement that you are using for `Select`?

Comment: import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
This import statement I am using.

Comment: it should work then, can you paste your entire code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you have imported a different `Select` class.

Please remove below statement from your imports and it would work fine:-

```
import org.openqa.jetty.html.Select; // This one you have to remove
```

To work with `Select WebElement` you need to `import` the `Select` from `Selenium`

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select; // This one you have to use
```

Hope it helps!